# Component Based Deployment in Angular 8

Tags: angular

How to achieve Component based Deployment in Angular 8 .
Suppose we have 10 component in our angular project and we want only 6 component is included in build then how we can do this .

Next time again we have to build and added some new component and want to deploy only these new component not change any thing in previous component then how we will do this . is there any option in ngbuild .

Answer (score 0):

You can play with the "exclude" attribute of tsconfig.json (got it from there https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6050#issuecomment-403571363) but apparently this is only working if the file is not imported in a file that is being built